# Ruby on Rails で作成したアプリケーションについての質問です

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

ゲストログイン機能を実装し、ゲストログインしている時のみ、画面上部に「current_or_guest_user.email」とポップアップがページ遷移毎表示されます。
不要なので表示させたいようにしたいのですが原因と解決方法がわかりません。

検証ツールで確認しても特にエラーは表示されません。

解決方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご教授ください。

user.rb

```rb
  def self.guest      #ゲストログイン機能
    find_or_create_by(email: 'guest@example.com') do |user|
      user.password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      user.username = 'Guest'
      user.introduction = 'Hello, I am a Guest User'
      user.location = 'Anywhere'

      unless user.profile_picture.attached?
        file_path = Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/default_profile_picture.png')
        user.profile_picture.attach(io: File.open(file_path), filename: 'default-image.png', content_type: 'image/png')
      end
    end
  end
```

[image: こちらが問題のエラーです]

Comment: 自己解決しました

Comment: 解決したことをコメントするだけではなく、情報共有のために何が問題・原因でどう対処したかなどの詳細を自己回答・自己承認してみてください。[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)